# VBA Loop Not Advancing Despite Appearing It Should Be

Tags: vba, loops

My program appears in the VBA screen to be working, but on the Excel doc it's manipulating, not so much.

It is supposed to loop down a root column, populating off of it to other sheets, until the root column comes to a blank cell. When I run the loop, it does loop, and the plus 1 shows that it took effect for RW variable, when I hover over it in the VBA stepo through process. Yet it just keeps entering values from the same row over and over again as if RW isn't advancing when I can see that it is, and it keeps copying to the same row, when again, I can see the RW variable advancing by 1 in the VBA editor.

Here's the code.

```
Sub ExportData()
Dim RW As Integer
    RW = 2
Dim CL As Integer
CL = 3

With ThisWorkbook
.Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "US"
.Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "CA"
End With

Dim SKUUS As Range
Set SKUUS = Sheets("US").Cells(RW - 1, CL - 2)
Dim SKUCA As Range
Set SKUCA = Sheets("CA").Cells(RW - 1, CL - 2)
Dim RootSKU As Variant
Set RootSKU = Sheets("tblTEMP").Cells(RW, CL)

AvailDate = InputBox("What is Available Date?")
PromoCode = InputBox("What is the Promo Code?")


'HeadersUS
SKUUS.Value = "Item #"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 1).Value = "MAX QTY"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 2).Value = "PROMO Price"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 3).Value = "AvailableDate"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 4).Value = "VendorNumOverride"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 5).Value = "PromoListPrice"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 6).Value = "BOGO ITEM #"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 7).Value = "BOGO QTY"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 8).Value = "ProgramCode"
SKUUS.Offset(0, 9).Value = "PromoCode"

'HeadersCA
SKUCA.Value = "Item #"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 1).Value = "MAX QTY"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 2).Value = "PROMO Price"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 3).Value = "AvailableDate"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 4).Value = "VendorNumOverride"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 5).Value = "PromoListPrice"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 6).Value = "BOGO ITEM #"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 7).Value = "BOGO QTY"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 8).Value = "ProgramCode"
SKUCA.Offset(0, 9).Value = "PromoCode"

Do

'Populate First Row in US
SKUUS.Offset(1, 0) = RootSKU.Value
SKUUS.Offset(1, 1) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 12).Value * 0.8
    SKUUS.Offset(1, 1) = Math.Round(SKUUS.Offset(1, 1).Value, 0)
SKUUS.Offset(1, 2) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 7).Value
SKUUS.Offset(1, 3) = AvailDate
SKUUS.Offset(1, 5) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 6).Value
SKUUS.Offset(1, 9) = PromoCode

'Populate First Row in US
SKUCA.Offset(1, 0) = RootSKU.Value
SKUCA.Offset(1, 1) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 12).Value * 0.2
    SKUCA.Offset(1, 1) = Math.Round(SKUCA.Offset(1, 1).Value, 0)
SKUCA.Offset(1, 2) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 10).Value
SKUCA.Offset(1, 3) = AvailDate
SKUCA.Offset(1, 5) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 9).Value
SKUCA.Offset(1, 9) = PromoCode

RW = RW + 1
Loop Until RootSKU = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: RW is advancing by 1 but SKUUS, SKUCA  and RootSKU ranges are set to static RW value which is 2.You should assign RW value to your ranges inside your loop.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure if I fully understand. So cut and paste the DIM for RW to inside the loop? Or create a different variable for the portion inside the loop and put that variable inside the loop? What would that code look like?

Comment: I moved the variable to inside the loop, but still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the variable to inside the loop, but still get the same result. After playing around with it a bit on the premise, I was able to get it to work like this. Thanks for the assist.

```
Sub ExportData()
Dim RW As Long
Dim CL As Long
Dim SKUUS As Range
Dim SKUCA As Range
Dim RootSKU As Variant

RW = 2
CL = 1

With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "US"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "CA"
End With

AvailDate = InputBox("What is Available Date?")
PromoCode = InputBox("What is the Promo Code?")


'HeadersUS
Sheets("US").Range("A1") = "Item #"
Sheets("US").Range("B1") = "MAX QTY"
Sheets("US").Range("C1") = "PROMO Price"
Sheets("US").Range("D1") = "AvailableDate"
Sheets("US").Range("E1") = "VendorNumOverride"
Sheets("US").Range("F1") = "PromoListPrice"
Sheets("US").Range("G1") = "BOGO ITEM #"
Sheets("US").Range("H1") = "BOGO QTY"
Sheets("US").Range("I1") = "ProgramCode"
Sheets("US").Range("J1") = "PromoCode"

'HeadersCA
Sheets("CA").Range("A1") = "Item #"
Sheets("CA").Range("B1") = "MAX QTY"
Sheets("CA").Range("C1") = "PROMO Price"
Sheets("CA").Range("D1") = "AvailableDate"
Sheets("CA").Range("E1") = "VendorNumOverride"
Sheets("CA").Range("F1") = "PromoListPrice"
Sheets("CA").Range("G1") = "BOGO ITEM #"
Sheets("CA").Range("H1") = "BOGO QTY"
Sheets("CA").Range("I1") = "ProgramCode"
Sheets("CA").Range("J1") = "PromoCode"

Do

Set SKUUS = Sheets("US").Cells(RW, CL)
Set SKUCA = Sheets("CA").Cells(RW, CL)
Set RootSKU = Sheets("tblTEMP").Cells(RW, CL + 2)

'Populate First Row in US
SKUUS = RootSKU.Value
SKUUS.Offset(0, 1) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 12).Value * 0.8
    SKUUS.Offset(0, 1) = Math.Round(SKUUS.Offset(0, 1).Value, 0)
SKUUS.Offset(0, 2) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 7).Value
SKUUS.Offset(0, 3) = AvailDate
SKUUS.Offset(0, 5) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 6).Value
SKUUS.Offset(0, 9) = PromoCode

'Populate First Row in US
SKUCA = RootSKU.Value
SKUCA.Offset(0, 1) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 12).Value * 0.2
    SKUCA.Offset(0, 1) = Math.Round(SKUCA.Offset(0, 1).Value, 0)
SKUCA.Offset(0, 2) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 10).Value
SKUCA.Offset(0, 3) = AvailDate
SKUCA.Offset(0, 5) = RootSKU.Offset(0, 9).Value
SKUCA.Offset(0, 9) = PromoCode

RW = RW + 1
Loop Until RootSKU.Offset(1, 0) = ""
End Sub
```